# Should I use an Interface for a database connection / model class

Tags: c#, database, class, interface

I am new to programming and I am attempting to create a simple canteen/ store managing application using WPF (This would be my first real world application built). The first step I figured I should overcome is to create a class that will take care of all aspects relating to the database. Currently I am using SQLite but would like to eventually be able to include support for a number of different databases. In short, I would like an opinion on whether the path I took in creating an IDatabase interface and then implementing it in a Database class makes sense or would there be a better way of doing it. Thanks! I included below what I coded so far.

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    bool IsConnected { get; }

    bool Connect(string connectionString);
    void Disconnect();

    List<Account> SearchAccounts(Account account);
    Account CreateAccount(Account account);
    Account GetAccount(int accountId);
    void DeleteAccount(int accountId);

    List<PersonCategory> SearchPersonCategories(PersonCategory personCategory);
    void AddPersonCategory(PersonCategory personCategory);
    PersonCategory GetPersonCategory(int CategoryId);

    List<Person> SearchPeople(Person person);
    Person CreatePerson(Person person);
    Person GetPerson(int personId);
    void DeletePerson();

    List<Transaction> SearchTransactions(Transaction transaction);
    Transaction GetTransaction(int transactionId);
    void AddTransaction(Transaction tansaction);

    List<Log> SearchLogs(Log log);
    Log GetLog(int logId);
    void AddLog(Log log);

    List<ProductCategory> SearchProductCategories(ProductCategory productCategory);
    void AddProductCategory(ProductCategory productCategory);
    ProductCategory GetProductCategory(int categoryId);
    void DeleteProductCategory(int categoryId);

    List<Product> SearchProducts(Product product);
    void AddProduct(Product product);
    Product GetProduct(int productId);
    void DeleteProduct(int productId);

}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link! It looks like that is where everyone is pointing me. Guess I'll need to learn EF before I start this project.

Comment: I am currently looking at EF tutorials using SQLite and it seems to me that there is no way to use the automation tools like the designer etc... unless you use SQL server which I am not. Is this true?

Comment: What Microsoft learned after many years was that designers suck because code generation sucks. The initial learning curve might be slightly steeper, but once you get the hang of it, it is actually way easier.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why people are commenting on *what* (to use) instead of *how* (to architect/write better code).

> Should I use an Interface for a database connection / model class

Most likely.  **This is all going to be my opinions, so here we go**.  Depending on how big of a project you're developing or what you're attempting to learn, typically decides how you implement it.  The following opinions are how I write code for most mid to large scale applications.

> I would like an opinion on whether the path I took in creating an IDatabase interface and then implementing it in a Database class makes sense

Generally speaking this is how many architects design systems.  You could call it `IDatabase` but then you're really suggesting/exposing how it does what it does.  *In My Opinion* you could just call it `IDataAccess` which is more general (what if you store everything in json or xml... technically those aren't databases, your data access could even be an external web api call to another system... who knows!).

Take a look and the [SOLID object oriented design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) specifically the L and I.

Typically what I'll do is something like a project that exposes data access:

`Project <company>.DataAccess.csproj`

```
namespace <companyname>.DataAccess
{
  // sometimes generic IMyDomainDA<IEntityType>
  public interface IMyDomainDA // I suffix it with DA for DataAccess
  {
    IEntityType Get();
    // etc
  }
}
```

`Project <company>.DataAccess.<ImplementationType>.csproj`

eg Company.DataAccess.EF

```
namespace <companyname>.DataAccess.EF
{
  internal class MyDomainDA : IMyDomainDA
  {
    public IEntityType Get()
    {
      //Implementation
    }
  }
}
```

Because I use a Dependency Injection framework (specifically Autofac, but you could do that same with Ninject or Unity or [insert framework here]) I can keep the implementation internal but register it with the DI Framework.  This means I only ever expose the Interface.  It also means that I could completely rewrite it with NHibernate or DAO or Dapper, register that version from that assembly (project) and as long as I follow the interface definition, anything depending on dataaccess wouldn't care *how* I implemented it.

This also means I can test code that depends on the interface.  I can NSubstitute (moq, rhino mock) the interface and test that code that relies on the interface calls the correct methods or whatever it's suppose to do without needing a real implementation.

Comment: Thanks for actually answering to my question and not just telling me what I should or should not be doing. Although, it does seem like I will end up using EF or something like that. I also lost you a little there with the `IEntityType Get()` not sure what that is?

Comment: You may or may not want to implement a [Repository Pattern](https://blog.falafel.com/implement-step-step-generic-repository-pattern-c/).  Don't think that link is the defacto standard, look around for reasons to use it and not to use it and how to implement it.

Comment: Ok, I will be looking into this in the coming days

Comment: I think that's because a lot of us are probably old enough to have worked on projects where we wrote our own data access layers and know it is a lot of work that delivers negative value over an ORM.

Answer (score -1):

I am suggesting to use Entity Framework, and it solves all your problems

Comment: yes it seems like that would be the way to go but I haven't yet learned the entity framework and I wanted something simple so I understand everything that is going on in the code